# Using a custom exit node for Tor?

Tags: exit-relays, proxy, location

I want to be able to change my geolocation on Tor, but I can't figure out how to do that. I'm a complete noob, so forgive me for my rudimentary understanding of how things work. Browsers can read the IP from Tor's exit node, and that offers a way to find the location of the IP address. So far I've only been able to set up proxies in positions other than the exit node, so they're not getting read like I want them to. Long story short, I want to be able to change my exit node to a Socks5 proxy. If that's not possible, even something like a web proxy would work as long as it offers the ability to change geolocation (browser->entry node->middle node->exit node->proxy->website)

I know that you can designate a preferred country using torrc, but that's not specific enough for my purposes. I also know that doing this will essentially eliminate my security if the proxy is traceable directly to me, I understand that.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Tor is hiding your personal IP by default. There is no need to use a proxy for that. Connect to Tor to browse to a website that shows your external IP to check this yourself. Tor wil also change your external IP every 10 or 15 minutes or so. Your perfectly save as long as you don't enter any personal information on websites.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Tor General FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit)

> Can I control which nodes (or country) are used for entry/exit? Yes.
>   You can set preferred entry and exit nodes as well as inform Tor which
>   nodes you do not want to use. The following options can be added to
>   your config file torrc or specified on the command line:

```
EntryNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint,...

A list of preferred nodes to use for the first hop in the circuit, if possible.

ExitNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint,...

A list of preferred nodes to use for the last hop in the circuit, if possible.

ExcludeNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint,...

A list of nodes to never use when building a circuit.

ExcludeExitNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint,...
```

> A list of nodes to never use when picking an exit. Nodes listed in
>   ExcludeNodes are automatically in this list. We recommend you do not
>   use these — they are intended for testing and may disappear in future
>   versions. You get the best security that Tor can provide when you
>   leave the route selection to Tor; overriding the entry / exit nodes
>   can mess up your anonymity in ways we don't understand.
>
> Note also that not every circuit is used to deliver traffic outside of
>   the Tor network. It is normal to see non-exit circuits (such as those
>   used to connect to onion services, those that do directory fetches,
>   those used for relay reachability self-tests, and so on) that end at a
>   non-exit node. To keep a node from being used entirely, see
>   ExcludeNodes and StrictNodes in the manual.
>
> Instead of $fingerprint you can also specify a 2 letter ISO3166
>   country code in curly braces (for example {de}), or an ip address
>   pattern (for example 255.254.0.0/8). Make sure there are no spaces
>   between the commas and the list items.
>
> If you want to access a service directly through Tor's Socks interface
>   (eg. using ssh via connect.c), another option is to set up an internal
>   mapping in your configuration file using MapAddress. See the manual
>   page for details.

You can search for node fingerprints by going here: https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html